# Android: Port CoreData database from iPhone to Android app

Tags: iphone, android, port

I have a CoreData database for an iphone app populated with a lot of data.

How can I efficiently use this database in an Android app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the underlying storage for your Core Data app is Sqlite, simply copying your .sqlite file over to Android will make it easy for you to read data, as Android supports Sqlite.

However, while it might be tempting to use the .sqlite file as-is, note that there is no guarantee that the database schema used by Core Data will remain the same in future releases. Table structure, column names, etc are not supposed to be known to your application and might easily be changed.